# How can I solve permissions error when importing MySQL databases with PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, permissions, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a web site that is based around a MySQL db.
Because I wanted to do it off-line first, I installed WAMP server on my machine. This has Apache, an SQL server, and PHP.

I created a database on my off-line machine. The database is called`OffDB`, created by user `OffUser`, with password `OffPwd`. I have exported it to an SQL file (less than one MB).
I want to import this db into my online db, which is called `OnDB`, created by user `OnUser`, with password `OnUser`. When I try to import in PHPMyAdmin, I get the following error:

> "User OnUser doesn't have permissions to access databse OffDB"

In the off-line PHPMyAdmin, I added a new user, `OnUser`, with password `OnPwd`, and granted it all permissions to OffDB. Then I exported OffDB again, and atempted to import again. It failed with the same error. Same thing if I add new off-line user OnUser, with password OffPwd, and grant it permission - upon import I always get the error.
How can I solve that?

Comment: Changing DB name for test and live environment was a bad idea IMO. If it's on your local XAMMP and you have no access externally then it would of been Ok to use the same names etc. Note for the future ;)

Comment: If the user does not have permission to export/import on your live server then you can't do this operation. Contact your server administrator and told him to grant permission to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the OffUser and OffDB to the live server, not the other way around.

Alternatively, make a backup that does not specify the database name and users (for the latter, look for options involving GRANTs, and disable those). `mysqldump` should have options for that, at least if you use the `mysqldump <database_name>` variant, as should PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Hello, thanks all for your replies! Indeed I should have chosen the same everything... beginner's mistake... I cannot seem to be able to edit privileges in the online PHPMyAdmin, and I'm not sure how to make a backup without databser name and users, as I see no options with GRANTS in PHPMyAdmin. Where should I look for them? Thanks again!

Comment: Problem solved: I created a copy of the offline DB with the same name as the online DB. Import worked OK then. Thanks all for putting me on the way! @webnoob - duly noted :)